# BI Publisher PDF separate column Output

Tags: oracle

[image]

I want to seperate this column as the output in pdf format in BI publisher and how to do it

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for "how to do it", 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTF layout helped me to do breakage by grouping the function. for more details use the creating rtf layout https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/bi.1111/e13881/T527073T564393.htm